# How to unbind from active directory while preserving a user account?

Tags: macos, user-account, active-directory

My account is associated with an active directory of a previous company i was working at.

What is the best way to unbind my account from the AD without losing my files? I have admin access to the machine, and all the files are locally available.

The account is admin/managed and mobile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Login to a different admin account.
2. Delete your account, choosing "Don't change the home folder" option.
3. Open Terminal and rename your home folder, eliminating the " (Deleted)" part -- sudo mv "/Users/yourshortname (Deleted)" /Users/yourshortname
4. Unbind your machine (Login Options tab, at the bottom)
5. Create a new account with the same short name.
6. Use the existing folder, when you're prompted.

An update to my comment of Sep 6 at 15:24 and part of #4 -- Apple has just issued a supplemental update that fixes this loophole. The text of their security announcement is:

> APPLE-SA-2013-10-03-1 OS X v10.8.5 Supplemental Update
>
> OS X v10.8.5 Supplemental Update is now available and addresses the
>   following:
>
> Directory Services Available for:  OS X Mountain Lion v10.8 to v10.8.5
>   Impact:  A local user may modify Directory Services records with
>   system privileges
>
> Description:  A logic issue existed in Directory
>   Services's verification of authentication credentials allowing a local
>   attacker to bypass password validation. The issue was addressed
>   through improved credential validation. CVE-ID CVE-2013-5163 : the
>   rookies of 42

Comment: Also, probably a good idea to delete the directory services and managed preferences from your library...but it probably won't be a huge problem if you don't do that.

Comment: thanks. i will test this over the long week-end and report back.

Comment: you might want to expand your answer regarding unbinding: you need the AD admin account for step 4.

Comment: In my experience, it asks for, but will still unbind without, the AD user/password.